# How to validate many forms in html using single javascript method?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having two forms for example login and register.

In login page i am having two fields namely username and password.

In register page i am having fields namely firstname, lastname, username, dob, and password.

Here we can able to validate the above forms using two different javascript methods.

**My question is :**

Is that possible to do using a single javascript method?

Kindly advice. Thanks in advance

Comment: Certainly. Just write a global validate function, and pass the form as a parameter: `<form onsubmit='return globalValidate(this);'>`

Comment: any example or reference site? So that it will be little bit flexible for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can.**
If you use some kind of a library that will do that. But your forms will have to be configured for those libraries either with another Javascript or additional HTML Element Attributes. Choosing a library greatly depends on other technologies/libraries/platforms you use. In Asp.net MVC you can easily use xVal for instance. Coupled with data annotations.

### Implementation suggestion

You could of course create your own. Something like *required* could easily be done. ALl form fields that are required can have an attribute `required=true`. You could then just go throu all fields and check this custom attribute and act appropriately.

This would make a universal form validation easily possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, I can recommend the following plugin
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

If you're not using jQuery, you should be :)